# Integration testing - test is_wp_error in the code?

Tags: testing

I'm testing ajax callback in my plugin that is used to import users from JSON file.

I have tested everything, but one thing. In my import callback I have:

```
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $generator->generate( 16 ), $email );

  if ( \is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    \wp_send_json_error( $user_id->get_error_message() );
  }
```

`$generator->generate( 16 )` is a custom random generator.

My integration tests for this method is all green, except for this part where I need to test if an error occurred.

I'm using WP-CLI for scaffolding the plugin, and I'm extending the `WP_Ajax_UnitTestCase`, following [this article](https://codesymphony.co/wp-ajax-plugin-unit-testing/) by J.D. Grimes.

Is there a way I can manually trigger the error while testing?

I tried mocking that function with `WP_Mock` and `BrainMonkey`, but with `BrainMonkey` I got a patchwork error, saying that the file that defines the `wp_create_user` was included earlier than Patchwork.

The test looks like this

```
public function test_import_users_callback_user_creation_fail() {
    $this->_setRole( 'administrator' );
    $_POST['nonce'] = wp_create_nonce( 'user_import_action' );

    $_FILES = array(
        'file' => array(
            'name' => 'dummy_import.json',
            'type' => 'application/json',
            'tmp_name' => dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/_files/dummy_import.json',
            'error' => 0
        )
    );

    try {
      Functions\when('\wp_create_user')->justReturn(new WP_Error('User creation failed.'));
      $this->_handleAjax( 'import_users_callback' );
    } catch ( WPAjaxDieContinueException $e ) {
        // We expected this, do nothing.
    }

    unset( $_POST );
    unset( $_FILES );
}
```

I know I'm not asserting anything, but I placed an error log in my original callback to check if I am getting `$user_id`s when creating users, and they show up in the terminal. So that means that my mock isn't working.

I also tried mocking after `$this->_handleAjax( 'import_users_callback' );` and after the `try/catch` block, no luck.

Is there a way to test this?